# Search contents of a file in google drive

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have built a document management system on top of app engine using java . I use Google drive to store all my document . This is document management system is just a part my application . I have provided user facilities like download , upload , versioning of documents etc making use of drive API . Now I have requirement for search the content of the file and when the content matches any of the files in drive it show me the file names where pattern matches .

I searched for drive API's but couldn't find suitable solution .

Need some help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see here :

> https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

and

```
fullText    string  contains    Full text of the file including title, description, and content.
```

in the drive SDK documentation